# How many smallest number moves need to measure 6 liter of water?

Tags: problem-solving

You are given two (unmarked) containers of capacity 9 liter and 4 liter and a huge tank of water. Need is to get measure of exactly 6 liter, of water. A move is either filling a container completely or emptying a container (either fully or partly). The smallest number of moves needed to do this task is?

Answer options:

A. 8
B. 10
C. 12
D. 15

Please explain your solution step by step.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What hav you tried? (Answer is A btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fill 9
2. Fill 4 from 9
3. Empty 4
4. Fill 4 from 9 again
5. empty 4
6. Put remaining liter from 9 in 4
7. fill 9
8. Fill 4 from 9